# Selenium not able to find element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web, web-scraping

Hi guys I'm trying to find an element in a website but for some reason it doesn't let me. The webpage is the login form of Reddit, I try to enter my username and my password but when I list all the inputs it only appears the top search bar. I suppose it is because It's like in another "tab" like that it pops up to the front but I don't know how to manage it. Thanks in advance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.reddit.com')
driver.set_window_size(1200, 1300)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Log In')
login_button.click()

username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input')
username.send_keys("test code to the form")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once Login button is clicked an `iframe` is opened so you first have to switch to that `iframe`:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'login')]"))
```

Also you have a problem is with `username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input')` since `input` is not an unique css selector.
Try this:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id="loginUsername"]')
```

Also, it would be better to locate the login button as following:

```
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"login")]')
```

Finally, after inserting the username and password don't forget to switch from `iframe` to default content with

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Cheers mate, appreciate it.